# Split string into alphanumeric and others

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I split a string into groups of alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric strings?

```
var str = "abcd !!hh8kK*( abcd efgh"
//some split logic that can give me
['abcd', ' !!', 'hh8kK', '*( ', 'abcd', ' ', 'efgh']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work even with additional Unicode characters from different alphabets.

```
var result = "abcd !!hh8kK*( abcd efgh".split(/\b/g);
```

In the code above we split a string with regular expression on word boundaries `\b` - [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Example Below:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

var result = input.value.split(/\b/g);

result.forEach(function(item, index) {
  output.innerHTML += "Matched item at index " + index + ": <b>`" + item + "`</b><br> \n";
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" value="abcd !!hh8kK*( abcd efgh">
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Is there possibility to add single quote in the scope of word boundary, It will help me catch words like shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```js
var str = "abcd !!hh8kK*( abcd efgh";
var result = str.split(/(\w+)/);
result = result.slice(1, result.length-1); // remove trailing empty strings
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Comment: Is JSON.stringify available natively?

Comment: @user961954 : [**JSON.stringify is available in all modern browsers and IE8+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: @JohnSlegers even in IE compatibility mode?

Comment: @user961954 : It's 2016. You should be able to ignore any versions of IE below IE8.

Comment: @JohnSlegers I just realized JSON.stringify is only for demo purpose. Peace!

Comment: @jcubic as James explained that this will include hyphens and underscore, this won't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
/([A-Za-z0-9]+|[^A-Za-z0-9]+)/g
```

[image: Regexper Visualisation]

And apply it using JavaScript's `match` method:

```
"abcd !!hh8kK*( abcd efgh".match(/([A-Za-z0-9]+|[^A-Za-z0-9]+)/g)
-> ["abcd", " !!", "hh8kK", "*( ", "abcd", " ", "efgh"]
```

This matches one or more alphanumeric character *or* one of more non-alphanumeric character.

I've not used `\w+` here as that matches both underscores (`_`) and hyphens (`-`).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I've not used \w+ here as that matches both underscores (_) and hyphens (-)."

Comment: @user961954 [jcubic's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36351232/1317805) uses the regular expression `/\w+/`. This places all alphanumeric characters along with underscores and hyphens into the same group (`"a-b_c!!"` would become `["a-b_c", "!!"]` which I assume isn't what you're after).

Comment: You are right! I don't want that, so that answer won't work for me, but I am evaluating a new answer from Rolice's answer  split(/\b/g).

Comment: I tested and split(/\b/g) works like a charm, so I will go with it. Thanks for your answer as well.